# Compute Correlation while forcing mean to zero

Tags: r

Is there an alternative to the stats package that gives the option to compute correlation/co-variance matrices while forcing the mean to be zero?  (i.e. cov = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)) and I would like the 2nd term to be zero.  I wrote it myself by looping through all the possible pairs but it is at least 10 times slower than the cor() function.

I know google is my friend but its almost impossible to google R and Correlation as R is the often used as the symbol for correlation ...

Comment: What definition of covariance are you using that allows you to drop the second term? I assume you're trying to calculate this value in a particular sample. In a sample, there is no longer an expectation so `E(xy)` is really just `mean(x*y)` in R.

Comment: Lets say I know the population mean of X & Y is 0.  But the sample mean might not be due to noise and I would like to force it to be zero when calculating the moments as well as correlation.